# Find the $\limsup\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} [0,\frac{1}{m}]$

Tags: limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

The question is to find the following:
\begin{equation}
\limsup\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty} \big[0,\frac{1}{m}\big]
\end{equation}
What I have started with is using the result of the Borel-Cantelli Lemma, i.e. if $\{E_m\}$ is a set of Lebesgue measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then:
\begin{equation}
\limsup\limits_{m \rightarrow \infty}E_m = \bigcap^{\infty}_{q=1}\bigcup^{\infty}_{m=q}E_m
\end{equation}
From here, can we just say that, by using this lemma, the answer is $\{0\}$. Not sure how to formalise this idea, any help or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: No need for measurability in this lemma in my opinion. I would say that the intersection of unions is the _definition_ of $\limsup$ of sets of real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$; let $x \in \cup_{n \geq m}[0, 1/n]$. Then $x \in [0,1/n]$ for some $n \geq m$. Note that $n \geq m$ iff $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{m}$; so we have $x \in \{ 0 \}$.

Answer (score 2):

The key of using this lemma (I think it's a definition actually) is to realizing which elements are *not* in the limit superior.

You can see that negative numbers aren't in any of the sets, so aren't in the limit superior either.

Given a real number $r > 0$, you can see that there is a number $M$ large enough such that $r > \frac 1M$. Then, $r \notin \left[0,\frac 1m\right]$ for any $m \geq M$.

This means, therefore, that $r \notin \bigcup_{m = M}^\infty \left[ 0,\frac 1m \right]$, which means that $r \notin \bigcap_{q=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=q}^\infty \left[ 0,\frac 1m\right]$, so that $r \notin \limsup \left[ 0,\frac1m \right]$.

Hence, only $r=0$ remains. I leave you to see that since $r \in \left[ 0,\frac 1m\right]$ for all $m$ , it is in the limit superior. Use the definition, the way I did.